# Closure for true private field in JavaScript using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, closures, typescript

I am trying to rewrite one of my useful JavaScript class with TypeScript.
In my JavaScript class I use closure variable self for implementing private field. 
It is useful in event handlers, for example `onkeypress`, where important to know invoker of event and current instance of my class.

```
var MyClass = function (valueHolder) {
            var self = this;
            this.valueHolder = valueHolder;

            MyClass.prototype.DoUsefullactions = function (value) {
                alert(value);
            }

            MyClass.prototype.onclickForHolder = function (e) {
                var value = $(this).val(); //value from attached input
                self.DoUsefullactions(value);
            }

            MyClass.prototype.GetSelf = function () {
                return self;
            }

            this.valueHolder.onclick = this.onclickForHolder;
        }
```

I can't find **how to make what closure variable  what will be available for all methods of the class without `this.self` syntax in TypeScript and make true private members in JavaScript way.**

Comment: Assigning properties to prototype in constructor function is not good. It'll assign this on every constructor call.

Comment: thank you, it's only for example

Answer (score 3):

There's an alternative function syntax for this. Simply use:

```
MyClass.prototype.onclickForHolder = e => {
    var value = $(e.target).val(); //value from attached input
    this.DoUsefullactions(value);
}
```

`this` will refer to the outer `this` and TypeScript will add a self-type variable behind the scenes.

Comment: thank you, i know this version for solving problem, i'am assuming  abstract solution exists in this situation in TypeScript

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 MyClass.prototype.onclickForHolder =(ev:Event) =>this.DoUsefullactions(this,ev);
```

Comment: It would be appreciated if you explain why he should try that.